# _strset_s crashes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The following code crashes while executing `_strset_s` I have given 80 as length in _`strset_s`. What could be the problem?. I enabled run time stack frame checkb option  `/RTCs`

```
char strToken[80];
_strset_s(strToken, 80, '\0' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to `_strset_s` has to be null terminated according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175784%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Since your string is not initialized to anything, it violates this invariant.

> If str is a null pointer, or the size argument is less than or equal to 0, **or the block passed in is not null-terminated, then the invalid parameter handler is invoked**,

The default "invalid parameter handler" is to crash, again from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The default invalid parameter invokes Watson crash reporting, which causes the application to crash and asks the user if they want to load the crash dump to Microsoft for analysis.

So I'd try Null terminating strToken first (or better yet do what Bo Persson suggests in his answer)

```
char strToken[80];
strToken[79] = '\0';
_strset_s(strToken, 80, '\0' );
```

Comment: The code was working fine for many years. It crashed only when I enabled run time stack frame checkb option /RTCs. why does it happen so?

Answer (score 4):

You can let the compiler do the filling by using

```
char strToken[80] = {0};
```

This will zero all the bytes of the string.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, why do you recommend `= {0}` and not `= {}`?

Comment: @ildjarn - Both are equally valid, but not all compilers agree on that. Some try to warn you that you might have forgotten the values inside the { }.

Comment: `static char strToken[80];`  also initializes with 0